# how to fill a row in a subcolumn inside a multi column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a multicolumn dataframe called `full_week` that the first column is the employees names and the other columns are columns with each weekday name starting from Sunday to Thursday. Each weekday column has 5 more subcolumns for different kinds of employee shift preferences. a visual explanation of the employee column next to one-weekday column for example:

`|Employee  |Sunday`
`___________|_____________________________|`

`|In|Out|Hours|Weekday|Workplace|`

In the beginning, the dataframe will only have NaN values. When i retrieve the employee input from the GUI I created about the shift information and stored it inside a dictionary, I want to take 1 row from the column above, for example, the row with index 0, and fill the NaN values with the dictionary that has the same keys as the sub column names.

the dictionary: `dd = {'In': '09:00:00', 'Out': '17:00:00', 'Hours': 8, 'Weekday': 'Tuesday', 'Workplace': 'Office'}`

I tried this code using `fillna` with the dictionary above but the changes are not saving, even when I write `inplace=True`:

`full_week['Sunday'].iloc[0].fillna(dd, inplace=True)`

I think the problem is about taking a slice from the dataframe but can't find the right solution to only fill the specific row of the specific chosen weekday column.

I have this function that eventually what you wrote returns `None`:

```
def mapping_the_request():
    global row
    global day
    choices = show_chosen_info() #--> the input from the GUI
    cols = ['Analyst','In', 'Out', 'Hours', 'Weekday', 'Workplace']
    d = dict(zip(cols, choices))
    
    for index, col in full_week.iterrows():
        if col[0] == d['Analyst'] and d["Weekday"] in full_week.columns:
            day = d['Weekday']
            row = index
            
    del d['Weekday'] #--> Deleting because i don't need it anymore.
    del d['Analyst'] #--> Deleting because i don't need it anymore.
    full_week.loc[full_week.index.get_loc(row), day] = full_week.loc[full_week.index.get_loc(row), day].fillna(d)
    return full_week

full_week.update(mapping_the_request())
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid I can't help any further if you don't improve your question. The code is not entirely clear (why you iterate over the whole dataframe and just perform an operation after the iteration? Is it just a lookup? In that case, there are better ways to do it. Also, I don't really understand why you call the `.update()` method. You should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're calling the `.fillna` method on the `pandas.Series` that is returned by your indexing and the `inplace` option can't really work as you intended. What you should do is to reassign the Series back to the Dataframe.

The second problem is that doing the indexing as you did it, you'll get a copy of a slice, see the [Pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for more information.

To achieve your goal, you should instead do:

```
full_week.loc[full_week.index.get_loc(0), 'Sunday'] = 
            full_week.loc[full_week.index.get_loc(0), 'Sunday'].fillna(dd)
```

Comment: i've edited my posted and add the function i use to enter the data.

Comment: Ok, but is there still a question related to that code? Otherwise, this is actually not how StackOverflow works. If [someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and you have no further questions you should mark it as accepted and/or vote it. There's no need to show us your final implementation.

Comment: @Tom Also, you rejected my edit because "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post". I strongly encourage you to have a look at [SO's guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) on what an edit is meant for.

Comment: ok ill look on the guidelines, sorry if i did anything not in the right way! i edited the post because the code you wrote, i tried it and it teturn None, so i though if i'll add the full function it will be more understandable if i did something wrong on the way.